# How can I initialize another value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I tryed to bind msg1 and msg2 value like below. It works properly.
If I change input text value msg1, msg2 change same value as msg1.

Javascript

```
var BindController = function($scope){
    $scope.msg1;
    $scope.msg2;
    $scope.msgChange = function(){
        $scope.msg2 = $scope.msg1;
    };
};
```

Then it comes to initialize msg1 with ng-init="123", of couse msg2 value does not change.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="bindController">
  <input type="text"
     ng-init="msg1=123"
     ng-model="msg1"
     ng-change="msgChange()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="msg2">
</div>
```

How can I initialize msg1 and msg2 keep same value, when it initialized.
Or how can I call msgChange() function at initializing msg1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it can work. I don't know it is good solution though.
I added init function, then initialize value and call function in ng-init.

Javascript

```
var BindController = function($scope){
    $scope.msg1;
    $scope.msg2;
    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.msgChange();
    };

    $scope.msgChange = function(){
        $scope.msg2 = $scope.msg1;
    };
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="bindController">
  <input type="text"
     ng-init="msg1=123;init();"
     ng-model="msg1"
     ng-change="msgChange()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="msg2">
</div>
```

I didn't know if it's available to call function in ng-init.
It works as I expected for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set them in the controller:

```
$scope.msg1 = $scope.msg2 = 123
```

Or you could use `ng-init="msg1 = 123; msg2 = 123"`

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.msgChange = function () {
    $scope.msg2 = $scope.msg1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller=ctrl ng-init="msg1 = 123; msg2 = 123">
    <input ng-model=msg1 ng-change="msgChange()">
    {{msg2}}
```

Comment: I actually want to put some process to msg2 with init value. So it might better change msg2 in function. The question was little simple to explain sorry. For example, I use initialized msg1 value for server parameter, and get msg2 value from server side, and more, I need call function, when msg1 text value is changed.

Comment: You can call `$scope.msgChange()` at the end of the controller then.

Answer (score 0):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat...you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

You can do this instead:

```
<div ng-controller="BindController">

  <input type="text"
    ng-model="msg1" 
    ng-change="setMsg2()" />

  <input type="text" 
    ng-model="msg2" />

</div>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('BindController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg1 = 123;

  $scope.setMsg2 = function() {
    $scope.msg2 = $scope.msg1 + 'hello';
  }
}]);
```